# Lightswitch prerequisites on ASP.NET webserver

Tags: silverlight, iis, iis-7, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am trying to deploy a LightSwitch application to a hosted ASP.NET webserver in my company. The application access data stored on a SQL Server. My webserver admin is asking me if there are any special prerequisites needed for it to run. I've been reviewing the deployment guide

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2010/09/23/configuring-a-machine-to-host-a-3-tier-lightswitch-application.aspx

The article lists that there was a server component, but that it might change when RTM arrived:

> NOTE: The team is looking at simplifying this process and possibly making the LightSwitch server component pre-reqs go away so this process will likely change for RTM.

This other MSDN article states that there are prerequisites.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg481779.aspx

My webserver admin keeps saying there's nothing to install on the ASP.NET web server other than .NET 4.0.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server setup procedures haven't changed since Beta 1 (although of course the runtime has changed). It's pretty simple; the [prerequisites article that you cited](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg481779.aspx) has the correct information. Basically the process is:

1. Install the Web Platform Installer if you don't already have it installed
2. Fire up the WPI and search for the LightSwitch runtime
3. Install!

As mentioned in the article, you'll need to decide whether you want to install a new instance of SQL Server locally with the prerequisites. If you've already planned for a production SQL Server, you'll want to choose the "without local SQL" option.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a specific answer, but I would stand up a VM with the appropriate version of windows server on it and run through an install on a do novo machine. Should confirm or deny what your server admin says . . .

Comment: hmm. i don't think I have any access to a windows server image. Would creating a normal window vw, installing iis, and publishing to that work the same?

Comment: Sure there is -- http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/windows-server/2008-r2-trial.aspx -- that said, a normal Windows SKU should do just fine for these purposes, main issue is you don't want to install lightswitch on it, you want it to pretend to be clean.

Comment: Thanks Wyatt. I'll give that a try and report back. I don't think I need access to the company network for what I need to test (it won't recognize the VM so it won't let it in).